# Change q by q object intensity in binary image

Tags: image-processing

lets say I have an image that looks like that[image]

now I want to apply an average filter to decrease the intensity of small objects then threshold to get objects of interest. The question is like this what is the smallest odd sized average  filter that would decrease an object of size q×q to one tenth of it value.  cant think of a way to approch this problem can any one help?!

Comment: Why not using some morphological operations like erosion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29 or opening http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_%28morphology%29 to get rid of the small objects?

Comment: well this is a question that was asked in a book I can't tell him why not use another method :D